# Logging and tracking changes through a order flow for support/helpdesk team

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, frameworks

I'm not 100% sure how to formulate my question. That may also be the reason that I'm not  finding anything on google.

I'm currently working on a system in .Net core 5. This system has to track a order through a few steps, eg. Planned, Booked, Finished.
Each of these steps can, for example, change the properties of the order, send a message to the customer or return a error message.

To handle problems with these orders, we have a support team to help the customer. We want them to lookup the order (through a custom website or framework, not decided yet) and give support, all based on the events/messages logged for the order.

I'm looking for good practices to set up a support system for this. Are there frameworks that i can look into? Does this have a specific name maybe?

We are currently using Serilog and drop logging into a database. Maybe this is the correct way to do it but this looks a bit messy. I have a feeling that logging with Serilog should be for the developers to solve errors and not to track events/messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To handle problems with these orders, we have a support team to help the customer. We want them to lookup the order (through a custom website or framework, not decided yet) and give support, all based on the events/messages logged for the order.

It seems a option-based question, so it's hard to give a 100% appropriate solution to implement this kind order flow system. But here are some suggestions:

For tracing order status changes, you just need to save and maintain order related information in data storage you prefer, such as database etc, so that you can retrieve/fetch these order status data and show your support team these orders info in your system.

And as you mentioned that Serilog etc logging frameworks are normally used for writting application logs to diagnose and analysis application issue/performance.

For some urgent order related task, which need to process in time, you can integrate queue message service into your system, so that you can run a queue triggered task to handle these business and assign this order related task to a specific support team or support member based on your actual scenario and requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i think that this will help me get on the right track! I will accept the answer in a couple of hours if there are not more answers.